# AEM DefaultGetServlet is getting called when I set my servlet to a SlingAllMethodsServlet

Tags: java, post, servlets, aem

I have an AEM Servlet that accepts GET requests and I am trying to update it to accepts POSTs as well, but when I update the servlet to accept both it starts calling the Default sling servlet instead.  I even made a very minimal servlet that does a basic Hello World

```
package com.mysite.microsite.core.servlets;

import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ModifiableValueMap;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ValueMap;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.OptingServlet;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet;
import org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONException;
import org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONObject;
import org.apache.sling.servlets.annotations.SlingServletResourceTypes;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.osgi.framework.Constants;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.HttpConstants;

import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component(service = Servlet.class,
    property = {
        "sling.servlet.methods={GET,POST}",
        "sling.servlet.resourceTypes=" + "cq/Page",
        "sling.servlet.selectors=" + "HelloWorld",
        "sling.servlet.extensions=" + "json",
        "service.ranking:Integer=1000"
    }
)
public class HelloWorldServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet implements OptingServlet {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorldServlet.class);

    /**
     * Add overrides for other SlingAllMethodsServlet here (doHead, doTrace, doPut, doDelete, etc.)
     */

    @Override
    protected final void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.getWriter().write("<html><head></head><body>Hello World!</body></html>");
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean accepts(SlingHttpServletRequest request) {
        /*
         * Add logic which inspects the request which determines if this servlet
         * should handle the request. This will only be executed if the
         * Service Configuration's paths/resourcesTypes/selectors accept the request.
         */
        return true;
    }

}
```

I tested the endpoint `/content/mysite/global/en/path/to/page.HelloWorld.json`
in the servlet resolver (http://localhost:4502/system/console/servletresolver)

And even on this basic servlet that isn't even overriding the doPost when I do a GET request, it calls the org.apache.sling.servlets.get.impl.DefaultGetServlet.  If I change the servlet to just use `SlingSafeMethodsServlet` and change methods to `"sling.servlet.methods=GET"`.  Then the servlet works fine.  Not sure what I am doign wrong here.

Comment: Are you sure your implementation of the `accepts` method works as expected? It's omitted here but it may  be the reason the Servlet isn't getting called.

Comment: Did you find the root cause?

Comment: I was able to fix by separating the sling.servlet.methods into two lines like this:


    "sling.servlet.methods=" + HttpConstants.METHOD_GET,
    "sling.servlet.methods=" + HttpConstants.METHOD_POST,